# iFrame within wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hi i am wondering if there is a widget or someway to put an iFrame in a program with wxpython.
An iFrame with the same capabilities as the HTML one, (ability to see other websites).

Thanks.

Comment: Funny spelling, did Apple get its hands on the HTML tag? Are you referring to the `iframe` HTML tag (presumably) or the `iFrame` format (see disambiguation page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython 2.9 has a new WebView widget, which can be accessed with wx.html2. It uses IE's Trident on Windows and Webkit on Linux and Mac. See http://www.wxpython.org/CHANGES.html for more information. I think there's a demo in the latest wxPython demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wxpython has an [HTML renderer widget.](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxHTML)

Is that what you're looking for?